# How to expose kafka metrics to /actuator/metrics with spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, jmx, spring-boot-actuator

I was looking a while and didn't seem to find the answer.
I'm using Spring boot 2, Spring Kafka 2.1.4 and I want to see the kafka consumer metrics in the /metrics endpoint of spring boot actuator.
What I don't understand is  - should I implenemt the exposure myself or is this comes out-of-box in boot 2 ?

If I to implement this my self, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Kafka exposes almost the same metrics through JMX, so I suggest you to create a custom `MeterBinder` to expose these metrics. Plus, you can create spring boot `autoconfigure and starter modules` to simplify the usage. You can find an example (ready to use) here: https://github.com/luiztoscano/spring-boot-kmetrics Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Targeted for micrometer v1.1.0 is the `KafkaConsumerMetrics` implementation of `MeterBinder`. This should expose the kafka consumer metrics you're looking for.

Source Reference:

https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka/KafkaConsumerMetrics.java

Comment: Is there an equivalent KafkaProducerMetrics available?

Answer (score 2):

add this config works for me:

```
spring.jmx.enabled=true
```

Comment: This might be the correct answer for the time of writing this. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there is no out-of-the-box one. You don't have choice unless to implement your own `MeterBinder`. For the Apache Kafka Consumer metrics per se, you should inject a `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` and call its `getListenerContainers()` and use their `metrics()` to bind to the provided `MeterRegistry`.

When you come up with something, feel free to contribute the solution back to Spring Boot.

Comment: The problem seems to be that there is no elegant way to migrate the KafkaMetric objects to Micrometer metrics. The only way I see is looping all kafka metrics and creating Micrometer identical metric for each of them

Comment: @MichaelAzimov I am looking to move the KafkaStreams metrics to micrometer. How did you proceed for the conversion ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me(For `Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE` and above):

```
@Autowired
private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);

    //More code here

    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object,Object> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    cf.addListener(new MicrometerConsumerListener<>(meterRegistry));
        
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

build.gradle
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
```

Metrics will be available at `/actuator/prometheus/kafka_consumer_<metric-name>`.